# Update query can not work in laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am appending value in database column with previous user id. I am writing code as below but it can not update query. Need solution.

```
$query_get_activity=DB::table('table_join_activity')
                   ->select('table_join_activity.*')
                   ->where('join_activity_id',$join_activity_id)
                   ->first();

$get_user_id=$query_get_activity->user_id;

$query_get_fcm_token=DB::table('table_registration')
                       ->select('table_registration.*')
                       ->where('user_id',$get_user_id)
                       ->first();

 $fcmtoken=$query_get_fcm_token->fcm_token;

 DB::update('update table_user_create_activity set accepted_join_id=CONCAT(accepted_join_id,$get_user_id) where activity_id=?',[$query_get_activity->activity_id]);
```

Comment: what error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this update query :

```
DB::table('table_user_create_activity')
               ->where(['activity_id'=>$query_get_activity->activity_id])
              ->update(['accepted_join_id'=>DB::raw('CONCAT(ifnull(accepted_join_id,""),'.$get_user_id.')')]);
```

Comment: hello i want update value but keep previous value in column as it and next value is added with,

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.$get_user_id) where (`activity_id` = ?)' at line 1 (SQL: update `table_user_create_activity` set `accepted_join_id` = CONCAT(accepted_join_id,",".$get_user_id) where (`activity_id` = 7)) this error found @Saurabh Mistry

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$get_user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `table_user_create_activity` set `accepted_join_id` = CONCAT(accepted_join_id,$get_user_id) where (`activity_id` = 7))

now this error occur

Comment: error remove but value can not updated in database plz need nelp

Comment: Yes at first there is no value in database

Comment: update tabname
 set colname= case when colname is null or colname =''
              then 'newString'
              else concat(colname,'newString')
              end  I want this upadte query but use concat_ws